# muutanja error in aws server and not in localhost

Tags: api, clojure, clj-http

Hopefully it makes sense to make a question like this here:

I have an python3 api which it uses Flask to serve. I also have an clojure app that makes a post request targeting the python3 api. To do so I use [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) with something like:

```
(client/post url-link
             {:basic-auth ["username"
                           "password"]
              :form-params json
              :content-type :json})
```

Now, when I test in my machine serving the python3 api locally, i.e,

```
(def url-link "localhost:port/api-name")
```

it works smoothly. The issue comes because I will serve the python3 api from the amazon server. So my thought was to use the link of the amazon server. But when I do so, clojure complains with

```
HTTP ERROR 500 clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Malformed application/json in :muuntaja/encode {:type :muuntaja/encode, :format "application/json"}
URI:    /api/sell-call
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Malformed application/json in :muuntaja/encode {:type :muuntaja/encode, :format "application/json"}
SERVLET:    -
CAUSED BY:  clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Malformed application/json in :muuntaja/encode {:type :muuntaja/encode, :format "application/json"}
CAUSED BY:  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) (through reference chain: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap[":full_message"]->clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo["data"]->clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap[":http-client"]->org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient["params"])
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Malformed application/json in :muuntaja/encode {:type :muuntaja/encode, :format "application/json"}
    at muuntaja.core$on_exception.invokeStatic(core.clj:284)
    at muuntaja.core$on_exception.invoke(core.clj:267)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5824.invoke(core.clj:2626)
    at muuntaja.core$create_coder$encode__10562.invoke(core.clj:346)
    at clojure.core$update.invokeStatic(core.clj:6198)
    at clojure.core$update.invoke(core.clj:6188)
    at muuntaja.core$create$_handle_response__10629.invoke(core.clj:443)
    at muuntaja.core$create$reify__10631.format_response(core.clj:486)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format_response$fn__10702.invoke(middleware.clj:132)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format_negotiate$fn__10695.invoke(middleware.clj:96)
    at ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__9403.invoke(keyword_params.clj:53)
    at ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__9461.invoke(nested_params.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__9535.invoke(params.clj:67)
    at compojure.api.middleware$wrap_inject_data$fn__11689.invoke(middleware.clj:96)
    at compojure.api.routes.Route.invoke(routes.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.basic_authentication$wrap_basic_authentication$fn__16405.invoke(basic_authentication.clj:157)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:384)
    at ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__1065.invoke(reload.clj:39)
    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__480.invoke(jetty.clj:27)
    at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) (through reference chain: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap[":full_message"]->clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo["data"]->clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap[":http-client"]->org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient["params"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3243)
    at jsonista.core$write_value_as_bytes.invokeStatic(core.clj:229)
    at jsonista.core$write_value_as_bytes.invoke(core.clj:221)
    at muuntaja.format.json$encoder$reify__10016.encode_to_bytes(json.clj:43)
    at muuntaja.core$create_coder$encode__10562.invoke(core.clj:344)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    ... 46 more
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) (through reference chain: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap[":full_message"]->clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo["data"]->clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap[":http-client"]->org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient["params"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3243)
    at jsonista.core$write_value_as_bytes.invokeStatic(core.clj:229)
    at jsonista.core$write_value_as_bytes.invoke(core.clj:221)
    at muuntaja.format.json$encoder$reify__10016.encode_to_bytes(json.clj:43)
    at muuntaja.core$create_coder$encode__10562.invoke(core.clj:344)
    at clojure.core$update.invokeStatic(core.clj:6198)
    at clojure.core$update.invoke(core.clj:6188)
    at muuntaja.core$create$_handle_response__10629.invoke(core.clj:443)
    at muuntaja.core$create$reify__10631.format_response(core.clj:486)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format_response$fn__10702.invoke(middleware.clj:132)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format_negotiate$fn__10695.invoke(middleware.clj:96)
    at ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__9403.invoke(keyword_params.clj:53)
    at ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__9461.invoke(nested_params.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__9535.invoke(params.clj:67)
    at compojure.api.middleware$wrap_inject_data$fn__11689.invoke(middleware.clj:96)
    at compojure.api.routes.Route.invoke(routes.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.basic_authentication$wrap_basic_authentication$fn__16405.invoke(basic_authentication.clj:157)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:384)
    at ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__1065.invoke(reload.clj:39)
    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__480.invoke(jetty.clj:27)
    at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    ... 46 more
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3243)
    at jsonista.core$write_value_as_bytes.invokeStatic(core.clj:229)
    at jsonista.core$write_value_as_bytes.invoke(core.clj:221)
    at muuntaja.format.json$encoder$reify__10016.encode_to_bytes(json.clj:43)
    at muuntaja.core$create_coder$encode__10562.invoke(core.clj:344)
    at clojure.core$update.invokeStatic(core.clj:6198)
    at clojure.core$update.invoke(core.clj:6188)
    at muuntaja.core$create$_handle_response__10629.invoke(core.clj:443)
    at muuntaja.core$create$reify__10631.format_response(core.clj:486)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format_response$fn__10702.invoke(middleware.clj:132)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format_negotiate$fn__10695.invoke(middleware.clj:96)
    at ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__9403.invoke(keyword_params.clj:53)
    at ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__9461.invoke(nested_params.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__9535.invoke(params.clj:67)
    at compojure.api.middleware$wrap_inject_data$fn__11689.invoke(middleware.clj:96)
    at compojure.api.routes.Route.invoke(routes.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.basic_authentication$wrap_basic_authentication$fn__16405.invoke(basic_authentication.clj:157)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:384)
    at ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__1065.invoke(reload.clj:39)
    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__480.invoke(jetty.clj:27)
    at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.22.v20191022
```

So, is it possible to say what I am doing wrong? Is there a way to work around it from the client side?

**Note:** The problem is that this is a code from my work and I would like to not share much of the specifics from it. I am asking because maybe I am missing a simple solution. If this question does not make sense to be in here, let me know and I will delete it.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The server thinks you are giving it invalid JSON data.  Print out the JSON you are sending and see if you can spot a problem.  Perhaps the json is being encoded differently in your local testing than when you send it to the server. Or, you have a different decoding lib for your local testing vs the json decoding the server is attempting.

Comment: A few things worth reviewing: Can you reproduce the API call with any other client (eg. cURL, Postman, etc.)? Are the credentials actually valid (maybe the response is an error, not in JSON format)? Is the response being truncated (maybe the response is too big), resulting in a broken JSON response?

Comment: Calling from other clients gets me the same error, calling without the json but an "{}" gets the same error. How can I tell how the amazon server decodes? I presume I can encode however I want with :form-param-encoding

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what happened.
There was an internal error in the python application in the amazon server, so when it returned to the clojure app, it did not know how to transform the error into a JSON (which is expected). So the solution was to deal with the error in the python application to return a JSON regarding the problem.

In my local machine worked because I had all non python dependencies to make the application work.
Thanks for the help!